# Unable to exchange `code` for Salesforce Marketing Cloud token

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to exchange a Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC) `authorization_code` for an `access_token` per the docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-app.htm

```
curl https://{my_subdomain}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token \
  --request POST  \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"grant_type": "authorization_code", "code": "{{my_code}}", "client_id": "{{my_client_id}}", "redirect_uri": "https://127.0.0.1:80/", “client_secret: “{{my_client_secret}}”, "scope": "audiences_read list_and_subscribers_write offline"}'
```

Yet it continually gives me the following error:

`{"documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm","errorcode":0,"message":"Bad Request"}%`

I have no idea where I am going wrong, any help is appreciated.

I was seeing "correct" errors when I was using an expired `code` and when my `client_id` and/or `client_secret` were wrong, but nothing after I pasted in the correct values. Perhaps it is my scopes?

According to the docs linked in the error code, `The token was not found in the request, or it is invalid or expired.`. This is the only error code that has `customcode == 0`. It is strange since I am trying to get a `token`, not pass one in, and that error code is associated with a `401`, which may or may not be what I am receiving back.

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) tag.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my `client_secret` in my data was using the incorrect double quote. It was a slanted double-quote. I discovered this when I tried using `Python3` instead of `cURL` and was converting my JSON above into JSON to pass to the `requests` library. I was able to successfully get a token.

So the answer is, the above is correct, just watch your encodings!